# How to load an html file into a webView for multiple targets

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, nsbundle

Inside my app I have a html credits file which I want to load into a webView. The code I'm using works perfectly fine for my main target. However later on I created a second target: the pro-version of the app but for this one the code doesn't work because url is nil.

Both targets are selected on Target Membership for credits.html
I have tried changing the Location of the file in the identity inspector to all possibilities with no success. 
I guess the file is somehow saved with a path only the main target can access.

```
if let urlPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "credits", ofType: "html") {
    if let url = URL(string: urlPath) {
        webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `Bundle(identifier:)` to get a bundle for a specific target. You can learn the Bundle identifier for each specific target by going to the Build settings of your target and looking at the `Product Bundle Identifier` variable.

```
if let targetBundle = Bundle(identifier: "yourBundleId"), let filePath = targetBundle.url(forResource: "credits", withExtension: "html") {
    webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url))
}
```